# SQL: How to convert future date to timestamp with UNIX_TIMESTAMP()?

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, future, unix-timestamp

I want to convert a DATETIME from a column to a UNIX TIMESTAMP. But the thing is that those dates are in a distant future, such as 2066-09-01... You can try those simple queries:

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2016-09-03 09:00:00' )` returns 1472886000 -> GOOD

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2036-09-03 09:00:00' )` returns 2104038000 -> GOOD

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( '2066-09-03 09:00:00' )` returns 0 -> BAD! WHY??

Any idea? Any workaround ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your rdbms is suffering from the Y2038 problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Is this MySQL?  They have a bug about this: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1872

Suggest handling this outside SQL if possible.  PHP's strtotime() and similar functions in other languages can play nice with MySQL's ISO date format.

Answer (score 2):

From [Unixtimestamp.com](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php):

> **What happens on January 19, 2038?**
>
> On this date the Unix Time Stamp will cease to work due to a 32-bit overflow. Before this moment millions of applications will need to either adopt a new convention for time stamps or be migrated to 64-bit systems which will buy the time stamp a "bit" more time.